# Surprising naming in table with two foreign keys to the same table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have the following entity (which was created using database-first). It has two foreign keys to the `AspNetUser` table.

```
public partial class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ToUserId { get; set; }
    public string FromUserId { get; set; }
    public string Message1 { get; set; }
    public bool Viewed { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime TimeStampUtc { get; set; }

    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser1 { get; set; }
}
```

I find that `AspNetUser` corresponds to `FromUserId`, and `AspNetUser1` corresponds to `ToUserId`. This surprises me since `ToUserId` is defined first in the table, I'd expect the `1` to be appended to the one that comes second.

I can code for it either way, but I can't code for it if the rules are somewhat random as to how this is determined. It's critical that I understand the rules and know which one will be associated with which foreign key.

Does anyone know the rules involved here?

Comment: Don't know. Maybe ordered by the foreign key constraint names? But you're supposed to rename these generated property names anyway in the edmx designer (which will survive edmx updates), so does it really matter?

Comment: @GertArnold: I was having trouble figuring out how to do that in a way that would survive EDMX updates. Especially since the update doesn't work very well and I usually need to delete all the tables and re-import them each time my schema changes.

Comment: @JonathanWood Do you? My experience with database-first is quite different. I have plenty of name customizations that survive updates. As long as you use the EDMX editor it's usually OK. An update mainly updates the store model, not the conceptual model (well, not all of it, at least not class and property names).

Comment: @GertArnold: Historically, updating the model from the designer has not worked correctly, producing flawed results. So I've developed the habit of just deleting and reimporting all the tables. It seems to have gotten better, possibly better than I was thinking.

Comment: @JonathanWood Sorry spoke too soon. Gert is correct, they will survive EDMX updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your edmx you can rename the navigation properties by clicking on the property and changing the `Name`. This will survive EDMX updates. However, if you totally delete it from EDMX and then build it from the database again, then in that case you will need to rename it again. Otherwise, you should be fine.